# Regex global capture of groups preceded by keyword

Tags: regex, pcre

There are lots of examples of capturing a word if NOT preceded by some keyword. I am trying to capture all the groups of digits within parentheses but only if it is preceded by the words "not allocated"

```
Job is not allocated to your organization (83) vs (1098), please contact support
```

This is the subject line. I want to capture both '83' and '1098' but only if the words "not allocated" appears before any of the capture groups.

A wanted to use a lookbehind but the ? quantifier can't be used between the lookbehind and the capture group:-

```
(?<=not allocated)?\((\d+)\)
```

Any assistance greatly appreciated. Expression needs to be PCRE (PHP) compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of the pattern, either match `not allocated`, or match the end of the previous match with `\G`. You may also enable the full match to be the matched digits substrings by using `\K` and lookahead for `)`, making the capturing group unnecessary:

```
(?:(?!^)\G|not allocated).*?\(\K\d+(?=\))
```

https://regex101.com/r/DboPrU/2

The negative lookahead for `^` is needed to ensure the `\G` doesn't match the beginning of the string as well.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind assisting with another variation of this? A regex just to capture the last set of digits in parentheses provided the string contains the words 'not allocated' i.e. just the digits 1098

Comment: Lookahead for non-digit characters, followed by the end of the string: `not allocated.*?\(\K\d+(?=\)\D*$)` https://regex101.com/r/DboPrU/3

Comment: @TrentRenshaw Just use `.*` instead of `.*?` in the regex.

Comment: Ah, right, since they're surrounded in parentheses and aren't plain digits, you can just greedy-match instead

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance and @Jerry .. I just went with * greedy and no (?!^) negative lookahead with \K reset of match: `not allocated.*\(\K\d+(?=\))`